# ¿Cómo puedo localizar un vehículo con google maps desde una aplicacion android?

Tags: android

Tengo un proyecto en la cual desde una aplicación Android se  debe ver Google Maps y ver dónde localizar un vehículo.

Gracias al GPS y cuando le des clic al GPS (carrito), te salga información sobre el vehículo.

Es un proyecto escolar, mi problema es cómo mostrar los vehículos y mostrar su información desde una base de datos en la aplicación.

Comment: Puedes aclarar tu pregunta?? No entiendo lo que quieres hacer

Comment: Hola  Alberto disculpa  mira :

Debo hacer una aplicacion android en las cual contenga google maps. Ok 
debo mostrar en la aplicacion mediante gps gracias google maps los usér guardado.

Ejemplo: Yo trabajo para la ford y kieren localizar este vehículo suyo desde la app y conocer kien lo tiene actualmente 

me expliqué bien ?

Comment: Hola @Sommer. ¿Y cuál es tu pregunta en específico? ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta mostrando el código con lo que intentaste hasta ahora? Así será más sencillo ver hasta dónde llegaste. Quizás te ayude leer [mcve].

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigbangdev.bussonora&hl=es_419


hola mira disculpa la app es como esta para ke se den una idea

Comment: @Sommer por favor, intenta [edit] la pregunta agregando tu código

Comment: Sommer, tu pregunta a mi me parece muy amplia tu pregunta, ve la respuesta de @Webserveis realiza una división de tareas de un proyecto como el que requieres, necesitas ir construyendo tu proyecto de esa forma. Trata intentar realizar cada parte y pregunta aquí más específicamente para que los compañeros te ayuden.

Answer (score 1):

Antes que te cierran la pregunta, porque me parece que no está muy claro lo que preguntas, si te falta una parte o es todo en conjunto.

Empieza por diseñar las partes, antes de ponerte con todo el proyecto a la vez.

**En la app del coche:**

- Obtener las posiciones: api de google play services, así no consume tanta batería.
- enviar posiciones a un servidor web usando api rest-ful

**Servidor:**

- Base de datos (estructura de campos)
- Creación del webservices API/Restful

**App rastreadora**

- consulta de datos mediante webservice
- posinonamiento gráfico en googlemaps

El centro de todo es el servidor, es donde deberías empezar primero, y mientras estructuras los datos, realizar comprobaciones con datos demostrativos.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro si esta es la respuesta correcta para tu pregunta pero usando la API de google no podrías acceder al historial de ubicaciones que el almacena? Lo comento porque Google ya detecta que vas en coche o en algún tipo de transporte y posiblemente el coche esté localizado exactamente donde Google paso de detectar que navegabas en vehículo.